# Tensorboard with PyTorch : toggle runs not working

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

I am using Tensorboard 2.3.0 with PyTorch summary writer.

As I run multiple training, I stored multiple log files in a directory such that

```
runs
├── test_1
│   └── events.out.tfevents.1614979424.MacBook-Pro-15inch.local.22634.7
├── test_2
│   └── events.out.tfevents.1614979441.MacBook-Pro-15inch.local.22634.8
├── test_3
    └── events.out.tfevents.1614991192.MacBook-Pro-15inch.local.22634.10

...(more logs)
```

The problem is that when I run `tensorboard --logdir runs`, it correctly shows all logs but I want to hide certain logs for example only `test_1`.
I think this should be possible by the toggle button at the left bottom corner but toggling it does not change the graph at all (it keeps showing all logs in the directory).

Comment: Did you try to refresh the tensorboard dashboard after toggling? sometimes it takes a while until it updates.